# How to get a vertical z axis in a 3D plot of mathematica?

Tags: plotting

I'm plotting some data as a 3D graph using mathematica.

```
Plot3D[{Pcase1[Dy, D\[Phi]], Pcase2[Dy, D\[Phi]]}, {Dy, 0, 1}, {D\[Phi], 0, 0.5}, Boxed -> False, AxesLabel -> Automatic, ScalingFunctions -> {"Reverse", None, None}, ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow"]
```

It generates a plot shown below.

[image]
The problem with this plot is that the Z-axis is not vertical. How do I make the Z-axis vertical?

**Update:** I looked at surface plot examples in Matlab documentation and found that the Z-axis seems to be vertical in their examples. One figure for illustration with high elevation is shown below:

[image]

Comment: Try `ViewProjection -> "Orthographic"`?

Comment: @creidhne It works! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @creidhne You can post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: You're welcome. Answering your own question is encouraged, but your answer should be more than a comment (it was automatically flagged as low quality) – answers should give a solution to the question. I changed your answer as an example.

Comment: @creidhne As a newbie, I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment by @creidhe worked for me. The `ViewProjection -> "Orthographic"` option sets the projection to preserve the apparent sizes of objects regardless of the distance from the viewer. It ensures that the axes are displayed orthogonally.